# Python: Utility function to determine when to roll over to next year (or roll back to previous year) for a given date and grace period

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I'm writing code for a birthday gift website. I have a routine that given a birthdate (in mm/dd/yyyy date format) needs to return back the birthdate for the current year, based on when someone purchases the gift.

It seems simple enough, but there is a complication. The routine needs to effectively account for the fact that people buy gifts a few months in advance, or a few months late, and that the year changes over in the meantime.

For example, if someone's birthdate is 12/29/1975 (Dec 29th) and the current date is 01/01/2023 (1st Jan), it is more likely someone is buying the gift for last year's birthday (i.e. 12/29/2022) than for this year's birthday (12/29/2023). Similarly if someone's birthday is on Jan 5th, and today's date happens to be November 29th, 2022, it is more likely I am buying the gift for that person's next birthday (i.e. 01/05/2023) than the current year's past birthday.

So you need to be able to clock the year forward in certain cases, as well as back in certain cases, and need to incorporate some kind of arbitrary grace period that determines when to clock forward or back.

By creating lots of different use cases and through trial and error I came up with the following function. It works (or at least passes all my use cases) but I'm struggling for an intuitive understanding of why it works, or whether there is a more elegant / intuitive way to do this. Also I happen to be paranoid that there may be cases for which this may fail and produce faulty results!

Any thoughts / insight would be much appreciated!

```
def determine_correct_year_to_use_for_birthdays(birthday, today=None, grace_period=120):
    """
    Determine the correct year to use for a date.  After grace_period number of days, you can assume the birthday is for the
    next year. Have to account for year changeovers also.
    :param birthday:
    :param grace_period: in days
    :return:
    # covert birthdate to this year's birthday
    # if (birthday - current date) is positive AND diff > (365 - grace period), go back one year
    # if (birthday - current date) is positive AND diff < (365 - grace period), keep current year
    # if (birthday - current date) is negative AND abs(diff) < (365 - grace period), keep current year
    # if (birthday - current date) is negative AND abs(diff) > (365 - grace period), move to next year

    """
    if not today:
        today = datetime.now()
    birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year)
    diff = (birthday - today).days

    if diff > 0 and abs(diff) > (365 - grace_period):
        birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year - 1)
    if diff < 0 and abs(diff) > (365 - grace_period):
        birthday = birthday.replace(year=today.year + 1)
    return birthday
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Why do you subtract 365 - grace_period? why not use grace_period directly? In general, the questions might be better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @FObersteiner - thank you! Am ashamed to admit I didn't know about codereview.stackexchange.com. Will remove the question!